# How do you make a complication adaptive?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-complication

[I was following this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/complications/index.html?#0) on how to add complications to a watch face using `ComplicationDrawable`. Something I can't figure out is how do I make a `ComplicationDrawable` responsive to the content? For example, if the data type for the bottom complication is `ComplicationData.TYPE_LONG_TEXT`, how do I make my `ComplicationDrawable` wider to adjust for the text?

[Here is my code for how I'm drawing the bounds for the complications](https://github.com/Nxt3/IO_Classic_WatchFace/blob/redo-complications/wear/src/main/java/io/nxt3/ioclassic/IOClassicWatchFaceService.java#L653).

I can't find an example of this anywhere so maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got everything you need in your code already. The only thing missing is to set the bounds based on the complication type. This is how I do it:

```
// Create a ComplicationDrawable object, and give it a Context.
ComplicationDrawable complicationDrawable = new ComplicationDrawable();
complicationDrawable.setContext(context);

// Set the ComplicationData from the onComplicationDataUpdate(int id, ComplicationData data) callback in your WatchFaceService.Engine class.
complicationDrawable.setComplicationData(data); 

// Set the bounds based on the current complication type.
Rect bounds = new Rect();
if (data.getType() == ComplicationData.TYPE_LONG_TEXT) {
    bounds.set(getLongTextBounds());
} else {
    bounds.set(getShortTextBounds());
}
complicationDrawable.setBounds(bounds);

// Set all other customization options, and draw the ComplicationDrawable to your canvas.
```